# Read all csv files in a directory and add the name of each file in a new column

Tags: r, csv, readr

I have this code that reads all CSV files in a directory.

```
nm <- list.files()

df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(nm, function(x) read_delim(x,';',col_names = T)))
```

I want to modify it in a way that appends the filename to the data. The result would be a single data frame that has all the CSV files, and inside the data frame, there is a column that specifies from which file the data came. How to do it?

Comment: Adding a `dplyr::mutate` after your `read_delim` should do the job assuming you have installed the `dplyr` package. `do.call(rbind, lapply(nm, function(x) read_delim(x,';',col_names = T) %>% dplyr::mutate(filename = x)))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `do.call(rbind, lapply(...))`, you can use `purrr::map_dfr()` with the `.id` argument:

```r
library(readr)
library(purrr)

df <- list.files() |>
  set_names() |>
  map_dfr(read_delim, .id = "file")

df
```

```
# A tibble: 9 × 3
  file    col1  col2
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 f1.csv     1     4
2 f1.csv     2     5
3 f1.csv     3     6
4 f2.csv     1     4
5 f2.csv     2     5
6 f2.csv     3     6
7 f3.csv     1     4
8 f3.csv     2     5
9 f3.csv     3     6
```

*Example data:*

```r
for (f in c("f1.csv", "f2.csv", "f3.csv")) {
  readr::write_delim(data.frame(col1 = 1:3, col2 = 4:6), f, ";")
}
```

Comment: Notice [`purrr::map_dfr()` was superceded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75062136/1082435) recently by the developers.

Answer (score 4):

[`readr::read_csv()`](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_delim.html) can accept a *vector* of file names.  The `id` parameter is "the name of a column in which to store the file path. This is useful when reading multiple input files and there is data in the file paths, such as the data collection date."

```r
nm |> 
  readr::read_csv(
    id = "file_path"
  )
```

I see other answers use file name without the directory.  If that's desired, consider using functions built for file manipulation, instead of regexes, unless you're sure the file names & paths are always well-behaved.

```r
nm |> 
  readr::read_csv(
    id = "file_path"
  ) |> 
  dplyr::mutate(
    file_name_1 = basename(file_path),                     # If you want the extension
    file_name_2 = tools::file_path_sans_ext(file_name_1),  # If you don't
  )
```

Answer (score 4):

For conventional scenarios, I prefer for [readr to loop through the csvs by itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75053203/1082435).  But there some scenarios where it helps to process files individually before stacking them together.

A few weeks ago, [purrr 1.0](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/releases/tag/v1.0.0)'s [`map_dfr()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map_dfr.html) function  was "superseded in favour of using the
appropriate map function along with list_rbind()".

@zephryl's snippet is slightly modified to become

```r
list.files() |>
  rlang::set_names() |>
  purrr::map(readr::read_delim) |> 
  # { possibly process files here before stacking/binding } |>
  purrr::list_rbind(names_to = "file")
```

> The functions were superseded in purrr 1.0.0 because their names suggest they work like `_lgl()`, `_int()`, etc which require length 1 outputs, but actually they return results of any size because the results are combined without any size checks. Additionally, they use `dplyr::bind_rows()` and `dplyr::bind_cols()` which require dplyr to be installed and have confusing semantics with edge cases. Superseded functions will not go away, but will only receive critical bug fixes.
>
> Instead, we recommend using [`map()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html), `map2()`, etc with [`list_rbind()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/list_c.html) and `list_cbind()`. These use `vctrs::vec_rbind()` and `vctrs::vec_cbind()` under the hood, and have names that more clearly reflect their semantics.

Source: https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map_dfr.html

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution using `purrr`, which removes the file extention from the value in the column `filename`.

```
library(tidyverse)

nm <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$")

df <- map_dfr(
  .x = nm,
  ~ read.csv(.x) %>%
    mutate(
      filename = stringr::str_replace(
        .x,
        "\\.csv$",
        ""
      )
    )
)

View(df)
```

## EDIT

Actually you can still removes the file extention from the column for the file names when you apply @zephryl's [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75053147/10215301) by adding a `mutate()` process as follows:

```
df <- nm %>%
  set_names() %>%
  map_dfr(read_delim, .id = "file") %>%
  mutate(
    file = stringr::str_replace(
      file,
      "\\.csv$",
      ""
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bind_rows()` from `dplyr` and supply the argument `.id` that creates a new column of identifiers to link each row to its original data frame.

```r
df <- dplyr::bind_rows(
  lapply(setNames(nm, basename(nm)), read_csv2),
  .id = 'src'
)
```

The use of `basename()` removes the directory paths prepended to the file names.